# testng.xml can't run classes

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-eclipse

I am right running in my testng.xml and as a testng Suite, but the class inside it doesn't run.
testng.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="TestAll">
  <test name="Test">
  <parameter name="first-name"  value="Here we Go is not displayed after log in!!! "/>
    <classes>
        <class name="tests.LogIn">
    </class>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

I am using additional Appium and JUnit libraries for the class.
Java code class:

```
package tests;

import java.net.URL;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;



import static common.Helper.*;
import static common.Element.*;


public class LogIn {

    private static final String USERNAME = "string";
    private static final String USERPASSWORD = "string";


    //Config and Setup a AppiumDriverInstance 
     public AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;
      public WebDriverWait wait;
      @Before
      public void setUp() throws Exception {
        // set up appium for ios instance
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone 5s");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "/path/to/file");
        driver = new IOSDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
      }


      @After
      public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
      }


      @Parameters({ "first-name" })
      @Test
      public void findFirstElement() throws InterruptedException {


          //check if FTU "Here We go" is shown
          iOsAssertExists(WELTBILD_DE_HEREWEGO_XPATH,"Here we Go is not displayed after log in!!! ", driver);

          //tab on screen to close FTU "Here we go"
          driver.findElementByXPath(WELTBILD_DE_HEREWEGO_XPATH).tap(1,100);
          Thread.sleep(3000);

      }

}
```

The class runs perfectly fine but I Don't know why testng isn't running it. It is a result of running:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  /Users/vorse/nga/ProductFamilyTests/AutomationTests/AppiumTest/testng.xml


===============================================
TestAll
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating testNG.xml and using junit annotation, thats why its not working,
you need to import this: import org.testng.annotations.*;

Also you need to use @Test of testNg, @BeforeTest/@BeforeClass in place of @Before, similar case for @After --> @AfterTest/@AfterClass

Answer (score 1):

From TestNG Documentation [5.12 - JUnit tests](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#junit):

> TestNG can run JUnit 3 and JUnit 4 tests.  All you need to do is put the JUnit jar file on the classpath, specify your JUnit test classes in the `testng.classNames` property and set the `testng.junit` property to true:
>
> ```xml
> <test name="Test1" junit="true">
>   <classes>
>     <!-- ... -->
> ```